# flowtype jsx element, weird bug with Element<*> (asterisk)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, flowtype

as below code, I use `Element<*>` for the type of **jsx element**.

```js
type Prop = {
    style?: StyleSheet.styles | Array<StyleSheet.styles>;
    face: Element<*>;

    disabled: boolean;
    anotherProp: any;
}
```

The usage of `Element<*>` (asterisk) is hint by *flowtype* compiler.

[image]

But then, every type defined after `Element<*>` is missing.

[image]

If I change code to `Element<any>`, then my type shows correctly.

[image]

But type `any` is not what I really need. What can I do to make it works?

I use [*flowtype* with *vscode*](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=flowtype.flow-for-vscode), but it seems the error was from `flowtype` compiler (or from [flowtype vscode plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=flowtype.flow-for-vscode)), so that might not related to *vscode* itself.

Comment: @zvona yes I tried both commas and semi-colons, they seem to work in the same way (but both not work in this case)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently an issue with the editor integration that causes certain types, especially ones using *, Despite this, note that the type is actually correct and will check based on what you wrote, even though it prints out wrong in the IDE.

For example, this code fails with a type error, while it would pass if the `any` type were actually used:

```
type thingy = {
  style: number,
  stuff: Array<*>,
  things: string
}

let t: thingy = {
  style: 19,
  stuff: 2, 
  things: "what"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a link about this *editor issue with certain type*?

Comment: There are several issues about printing of types: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3Atype-at-pos of which this is one case.

Comment: I got `(unknown)` almost on every type with `type-at-pos` command...ouch. Even a very simple one ex: `type Prop = 1 | 2`. But the line number of type is correct.